# ¿Suena raro preguntar "¿me das tu teléfono?" en Hispanoamérica?

Tags: expresiones, diferencias-regionales, preguntas

Ayer asistí a un cumpleaños de un niño de padres venezolanos. En un momento dado oí a alguien preguntar a un miembro de la familia si le daba su teléfono, y este respondió "mejor te doy mi número, ¿no?".

En España solemos pedir el teléfono de alguien como forma abreviada de referirnos al "número de teléfono", pero ahora no sé si la respuesta se debe a que esta expresión suena rara en Hispanoamérica (o, al menos, en Venezuela), o simplemente a que el aludido era un gracioso.

¿Suena raro en Hispanoamérica pedirle el teléfono a alguien para referirse al número de teléfono?

Comment: Ya escuché "teléfono" como sinónimo de "número de teléfono" várias veces in Sudamérica. Creo que el tipo era un gracioso.

Comment: En cuanto a Mexico se refiere, estoy de acuerdo con Alan.

Comment: De uso común en **Colombia**

Comment: personalmente, he hecho esa broma muchas veces, soy española... y también pido el número, sobreentendiendo de teléfono

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para estos casos usamos, en Argentina, tanto "número" como "teléfono" (por "número de teléfono"). Como el teléfono móvil se llama aquí "(teléfono) celular", también decimos "dar/pedir el celular" (o "el celu" a menos que la cosa sea muy formal). Si alguien quiere referirse al teléfono de línea terrestre, cableado, aquí se habla de "el (teléfono) fijo". Es habitual pedir "dame tu teléfono", "¿me darías tu celular?", etc.

No creo que en el resto de Hispanoamérica ocurra algo muy diferente, aunque quizá haya otras palabras específicas para los tipos de línea telefónica.

Aunque el uso de estas expresiones metonímicas es totalmente habitual, no falta el gracioso que bromea con ellas ("Te puedo dar mi teléfono." "Gracias, ¿no lo vas a usar más?", etc.). Hace tiempo que no escucho esa clase de bromas, sin embargo.

Comment: En Francia se dice much "coordinés".  Tambien en español se puede decir "coordenadas" o "datos"?  Y @Charlie tambien.

Comment: En Chile también se usa "dame tu teléfono"para referirse al número, y los chistosos se aprovechan de vez en cuando igual.

Comment: "Dame tus datos" suena algo policial. "Dame tus coordenadas" alguien puede usarlo irónicamente. "Dame tu contacto" es otra posibilidad (a partir de que el registro de una persona en un teléfono se llama "contacto").